# Image Transparency doesn't work with alpha mode and alpha blend in both eevee and cycles

Tags: image, transparency, blend-modes

I followed a tutorial, where I can make custom leaves for trees. I added an image as a plane and I should switch in blend mode from opaque to alpha clip but it does not work. It looks like bevore without any change. I tried it with all rendering modes and also alpha blend and alpha clip. The image is a PNG file with a transparent BG but in blender layout mode it shows the BG black. What did I do wrong? Here is the YT tut: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrfIRDw88bM [image]

Comment: Hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accidentally reproduce the problem. I was able to fix it by reloading the image.

First unlink the existing image by pressing the x next to image name.

[image]

Next reload the image by pressing Open and search your image.

[image]

You should share your blend file if this doesn't work.

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/R3rxgANe   ←  Didn't work but thanks anyway.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem with your file. Your image file was missing so I tried another image. I assume there might be something wrong with your png.